# package-selected-packages. What is it useful for?

Tags: package

What is the usefulness of setting

```
(setq
 package-selected-packages
 '(auctex                 ;
   jedi                   ; 
   magit                  ;
etc))
```

Doesn't emacs set the user-installed packages in package-selected-packages?
What would we be doing if we override this variable?

Comment: "This variable is used by `package-autoremove` to decide
which packages are no longer needed.
You can use it to (re)install packages on other machines
by running `package-install-selected-packages`."

Comment: So what if I have other packages manually installed by setting setq outside that variable? How will they be affected?

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry.  The quoted docstring tells you what that variable does, and I assume it will have those effects regardless of how it's set.

Comment: So the variable just stores packages that we always want to keep. Are these installed/updated everytime we start emacs?

Comment: No.  Is there some reason why you thought that might happen?

Comment: Im new in Emacs so I'm trying to understand the difference between having those packages specified in that variable or having them specified individually "setq 'nameofpackage").

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the latter alternative.  What does that look like in elisp code, and what do you think it does?  `(setq nameofpackage VALUE)` sets a variable called `nameofpackage` to value VALUE.  It doesn't *do* anything else, unless that variable has a particular purpose in other code.

Comment: @phils By the latter alternative I mean having (setq nameofpackage t) instead of "(setq
 package-selected-packages  '(list of names of package)". What would be the difference?

Comment: There's nothing similar about them.  `(setq nameofpackage t)` won't tell the package system anything.  It just sets a variable.  If no other elisp uses a variable by that name, then it essentially has no effect whatsoever.  If that *is* a variable which is used by other code (such as, but not necessarily, the package in question), then you'd have to read the docstring for that variable to learn what the effect of setting it to `t` would be.

Comment: Setting the variable `package-selected-packages` has an effect because there is elisp code in the package manager which uses that variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the variable’s documentation:

> Store here packages installed explicitly by user.

Whatever you explicitly install (e.g. with the `package-install` command, or with a package “manager” like `use-package`), gets into this variable.

> This variable is fed automatically by Emacs when installing a new package.

So it happens automatically! In fact, it gets saved to your `custom-file` if set via `customize` (which `package.el` does for you).

Still from the documentation (also mentioned by @phils in a comment)

> This variable is used by `package-autoremove` to decide
> which packages are no longer needed.

Whenever you issue the `package-autoremove` command it consults this variable. `package-autoremove` will remove everything that is

- not marked as explicitly installed (ie. not in this list), and
- not a dependency of an explicitly installed package.

The documentation also tells another use-case:

> You can use it to (re)install packages on other machines
> by running `package-install-selected-packages`.

So simply populate this variable manually, and use that command to install your favourite packages on all your machines.

---

To have a better picture, go to the package manager using `list-packages`. You will see a bunch of

- `available` packages; these are available in the configured repositories (see `package-archives`), but not installed on your system
- `installed` packages; these are what you installed explicitly. This list is exactly the same as your `package-selected-packages`.
- `dependency` packages; these are packages that are installed on your system, but that are not in `package-selected-packages`. Under normal circumstances these are installed as dependencies of other packages
- `built-in` packages; these are shipped with your Emacs installation and always available. You can’t remove them.
- `obsolete` packages; these are packages you have installed, but there is a newer version available
- `incompat` packages are packages that can’t be installed on your system. The reason is always stated by `describe-package`, e.g. “because it depends on Emacs 27” or “because it depends on uninstallable packages”.

For (much) more info, see the [emacs(Packages)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Packages.html) info node.

Comment: Thanks, so clear and extensive. I primarily asked because, even if the packages I install get copied into that variable in custom.el, I have "setq package-selected-packages" in my other init file which is run the last when loading emacs. So any user could tailor this list in case we don't want all packages we have at the moment (normally I install many packages per day just to test and forget about them, so here the idea is that I should keep the ones relevant). Does this make sense?

Comment: Actually, whatever works for you. ☺ I add packages i want to test to my config file with `use-package`, and if i donʼt need them, i remove them from the config. I never set package.el variables directly anywhere.